Sigma algebra generated by the coordinate projection in a model with 2 coin tosses
I have a bit of a knot in my brain and can not figure out, what the following generated sigma algebra really is.
Let $\Omega=\{0,1\}^2$ and $$X_1((\omega_1,\omega_2))=\omega_1,\quad X_2((\omega_1,\omega_2))=\omega_2$$ the coordinate projections.
I want to compute the sigma algebra $\mathcal A:=\sigma(X_1,X_2)=\sigma(\sigma(X_1)\cup\sigma(X_2))$. When I do that, i get $\mathcal A=2^\Omega$.
Here is my thought: A sigma algebra is closed under any set operation, since every set operation  can be described by union, intersection and complement.
Let $A:=\{X_1=1\}, B:=\{X_2=1\}$. Clearly $\sigma(X_1)=\{\emptyset,A,A^c,\Omega\}$ and similarly $\sigma(X_1)=\{\emptyset,B,B^c,\Omega\}$.
Then $A$, $B$, $A^c$, $B^c$, $A\cup B$, $A^c\cup B$, $A\cup B^c$, $A^c\cup B^c$, $A\cap B$, $A^c\cap B$, $A\cap B^c$, $A^c\cap B^c$, $A\bigtriangleup B$, $(A\bigtriangleup B)^c$ are in $\mathcal A$. These 14 different sets plus $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ constitute the power set, which has 16 elements. I was strongly convinced, the sigma algebra generated by the coordinate projections is smaller than the power set. Isn't that the point of all the extension theorems?
So the question is: What am I doing wrong?

The sigma algebra generated by the coordinate projections may be the power set. Specially for such small $\Omega$.

Thank you for pointing this out. I convinced myself, that this is the case. The point where i tripped up myself is that the sequence $\mathcal F_n=\mathcal P({0,1}^n)$ und thus $\mathcal F_\infty=\sigma\big(\bigcup_n \mathcal F_n\big)$ should still be smaller than $\mathcal P({0,1}^{\mathbb N})$.
